# Fix duplicate working copies in Xcode with SVN

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have an Xcode project I am working on with several other people. Everything has been going fine until recently source control (SVN) has shown up with two working copies on my computer. One of them is the actually project (what I want) but the other one has become the Asset Catalog somehow. How do I fix this?

[image: Xcode 5.1]

Answer (score 1):

Check in all your changes, and try to clean up working copy if still it doesn't work delete the working copy and check fresh repo code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done this but after a couple of days of commits it always seems to come back.